# Sumar valores array json.parse

Tags: jquery, javascript-objeto

Tengo este código *JQuery* que recibe un array desde un PHP y necesito sumar el total de los valores.

Los valores serán siempre los mismos por lo que se podría multiplicar el valor por el total de arreglos del array o algo similar, cualquier aporte me sirve, estoy aprendiendo jQuery, gracias!!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    buscaBoletas();
    function buscaBoletas(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '../includes/busca-boletas-pendientes.php',
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(response){
                console.log(response);
                let json = JSON.parse(response);
                let html = '';
                json.forEach(resp=>{
                    html +=`
                    <div>
                    ${resp.id}
                    ${resp.id_reserva}
                    ${resp.nombre_cliente}
                    ${resp.rut_cliente}
                    ${resp.fecha}
                    ${resp.hora}
                    ${resp.direccion}
                    ${resp.valor}
                    </div>
                    `
                })
                $('#respuesta').html(html);
            }
        })   
   } 
});
```

El array:

> ```
> [{"id":"199","id_reserva":"469","nombre_cliente":"maxi","rut_cliente":"17200200-5","fecha":"26\/02\/2021","hora":"20:00","direccion":"av.providencia 1234, providencia.",**"valor":20000**},{"id":"201","id_reserva":"471","nombre_cliente":"testing","rut_cliente":"17201201-5","fecha":"13\/02\/2021","hora":"20:00","direccion":"av.providencia 1234, providencia.",**"valor":20000**}]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno por si le interesa a alguien más, solo agregué este código por debajo del recorrido del `array`, después se imprimen en pantalla en `divs`:

```
let total = 0;
json.forEach(function(sum){
    total += parseInt(sum.valor);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bien como tu dices tienes un Array de un objetos, lo que tienes que hacer es recorrerlo y recorres cada objeto, si el objeto contiene la key 'valor' sumas el valor del interior. Aquí te dejo la solución que hayado según lo que he entendido.

```
const myArr = [{"id":"199","id_reserva":"469","nombre_cliente":"maxi","rut_cliente":"17200200-5","fecha":"26\/02\/2021","hora":"20:00","direccion":"av.providencia 1234, providencia.","valor":20000},{"id":"201","id_reserva":"471","nombre_cliente":"testing","rut_cliente":"17201201-5","fecha":"13\/02\/2021","hora":"20:00","direccion":"av.providencia 1234, providencia.","valor":20000}]
    const realizarSuma = (array) => {
        let valores = 0;
        array.forEach(element => {
            for(const property in element){
                if(property == 'valor'){
                    valores += element[property];
                }
            }
        });
        return valores;
    }
    console.log(realizarSuma(myArr))
```

**EDIT: **
Me he equivocado y me he liado, te he metido un segundo bucle innecesario, directamente puedes accder con un forEach y cojes el nombre de la llave del valor y lo concatenas que es más corto. Sorry :-)

```
const myArr = [{"id":"199","id_reserva":"469","nombre_cliente":"maxi","rut_cliente":"17200200-5","fecha":"26\/02\/2021","hora":"20:00","direccion":"av.providencia 1234, providencia.","valor":20000},{"id":"201","id_reserva":"471","nombre_cliente":"testing","rut_cliente":"17201201-5","fecha":"13\/02\/2021","hora":"20:00","direccion":"av.providencia 1234, providencia.","valor":20000}]
    const realizarSuma = (array) => {
        let valores = 0;
        array.forEach(element => {
            valores += element.valor
        });
        return valores;
    }
    console.log(realizarSuma(myArr))
```